# Modify a variable in a data frame, only for some levels of a factor (possibly with dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Sample df:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(runif(10,0,2*pi),runif(10,0,360)), group = gl(n = 2, k = 10, labels =c("A","B")))
```

I want to modify `x` only for group `A` (convert it to degrees). With `base` I just do:

```
df <- within(df,x[group == "A"] <- x[group == "A"]*180/pi)
```

I was wondering if there could be a way to do this with `dplyr`. This is wrong:

```
df <- df %>% filter(group == "A") %>% mutate(x = x*180/pi)
```

Because it returns only the subset of `df` where `group == "A"`. Is there a (simple) way to do this, or is this a case where `base` trumps `dplyr` for ease of use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` to create the logical condition, and based on that we either do the arithmetic calculation or `else` return the original values.

```
df %>%
    mutate(x = ifelse(group=="A", x*180/pi, x))
```

Or as  @AlexIoannides mentioned, `if_else` from `dplyr` can be used so as the `type` should be taken care of.

---

In `data.table`, this can be done by assignment in place and should be more efficient.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[group=="A", x := x*180/pi]
```

Comment: Even simpler than `base`. Thanks!

Comment: `dplyr` has it's own type-safe(r) version of `ifelse` - `if_else` that is worth using.